# Passing scope between pages without define an angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i would like to open a new jsp page by passing the $scope because i would like to use an array response created in the first one.
Example of my test.js:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('test', [])
    .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, communication, serviceRequest,$window) {

        // header example
        $rootScope.pageTitle = 'DEMO';
        $rootScope.pageSubtitle = 'Demo';

        var successCallback = function(response) {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
            $scope.testResponseObj = response;
            $scope.testResponse = JSON.stringify(response);
            $scope.testResponseSerialized = angular.fromJson(response);
            $window.open("index2.jsp", '_blank','heigth=600,width=600');   // may alse try $window
        };
```

Do you have some advices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var $yourFile = $window.open("index2.jsp","_blank","width=250,height=100,left=10,top=150");

$yourFile.response = response;
```

AND in your child controller:

```
var response = $window.response;
```